# Enable external access to local website with www binding

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm developing a website using ASP.NET & IIS.
On my dev machine I've set the site's binding to be accessible using www.mysite.com address instead of http://localhost/mysite (by changing also the hosts file of the machine).

How can I enable access to this site from other PCs on the network using the same address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to do this but you can make an entry in your dns or just add the entry to the host file of the other PCs too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an appropriate entry to the hosts file on each client that associates either your client IP address to the www.mysite.com domain name (A record), works if your client has a static IP or a fixed DHCP assignment, or you can add it as a canonical name for your client domain name (CN record).